# Setting selected table view row to top of table view swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view inside my project and I would like to modify it so that when a row is tapped, even if that row is at the bottom of the screen, that row then scrolls up to the top of the table view, how would I go about doing that? What uitableview methods must be manipulated? 
Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

This post is very old and I take it you found a solution with method:

Swift 4:
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

Was just looking at doing the same so thought I'd post this just in case.